# How to combine decorated parameters into a single object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, nestjs, decorator

I have a NestJS controller with about a dozen methods that look like this:

```
@Post(':id/something')
async doSomething(
    @Param('id', ParseUUIDPipe) id: string,
    @Body() body: SomethingDto,
    @AuthUser() updater: IAuthUser,
    @UploadedFiles() attachments: File[],
) {

    // each endpoint does something totally different,
    // and the DTO type is different for each endpoint.
    // but other than that the parameters are identical
}
```

In this instance, the `Param` and `Body` are from `@nestjs/common`, the `AuthUser` is a custom decorator, and `UploadedFiles` is from `@nestjs/multer`.

Is there a way to refactor this into a single parameter decorator, that can then be applied to a parameter object?

```
@Post(':id/something')
async doSomething(@SomeDecorator(SomethingDto) params: Params<SomethingDto> {
    // I want something just like this
    const { id, body, user, attachments } = params;
}
```

I've seen ways to do similar things with class and property decorators, but absolutely nothing I've found so far applies to parameter decorators.

Comment: Doesn't this just make it more annoying to edit the parameter types and decorators?

Comment: @katniss Generally, it probably would. But in this one specific instance, what I described here would make my life significantly easier if it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that (as of today).

Since NestJS injects values on demand using an internal dependency injection mechanism, it needs to know which values to inject in the first place. If you don't explicitly specify the values (like I thought to suggest in a previous edit), DI won't inject anything; and you cannot extract *something* from *nothing*.

There is probably a solution to inject raw `req` and `res` objects through `@Req()` and `@Res()` decorators, and use those, but at this point you are better off [writing a middleware](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware).

What you can do, that adds a little bit of hope, is you can dig into the NestJS's DI mechanism (I think, it uses a third-party package) and see how exactly it figures to inject the values to those parameters. This is potentially very insightful.

Answer (score 0):

*Technically* you could create one mega decorator, that combines all of these as a [custom parameter decorator](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators#param-decorators), but I would *highly* recommend against this. You'll end up with a very hard to use, hard to maintain decorator, that barely does validation, and would require some very difficult to maintain DTOs to get that to work.

**If** you still want to do this, it'll end up looking something like

```js
export const SomeMegaDecorator = createParamDecorator((data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionCOntext) => {
  const req = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
  return {
    params: req.params,
    user: req.user,
    body: req.body,
    files: req.files,
    file: req.file,
    query: req.query
  }
});
```

You'd use it like `@SomeMegaDecorator() { params, user, body, files, file, query }: SomeReallyUglyDto`